# N-page sequences in XSL-FO

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I need to make PDF with different text's color in the header for each 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th page. I.e.:

- 1st page - blue text
- 2nd page - green text
- 3rd page - red text
- 4th page - yellow text
- 5th page - blue text (same as for 1st page)
- 6th page - green text (same as for 2nd page)
- 7th page - red text (same as for 3rd page)
- 8th page - yellow text (same as for 4th page)
- 9th page - blue text (same as for 1st page)
  ...

It would be possible to make by something like this:

```xml
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="document">
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="first" maximum-repeats="1"/>
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="second" maximum-repeats="1"/>
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="third" maximum-repeats="1"/>
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="four" maximum-repeats="1"/>
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="first" maximum-repeats="1"/>
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="second" maximum-repeats="1"/>
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="third" maximum-repeats="1"/>
    <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="four" maximum-repeats="1"/>
....
</fo:page-sequence-master>
```

but I don't know a pages count in resulted PDF (it may be 1000) and I don't like to put a lot of `<fo:repeatable-page-master-reference`.

XSL-FO processor: Apache FOP.

Comment: FWIW, AH Formatter has an `axf:repeat-page-sequence-master` extension for this. (See https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#repeat-page-sequence-master.) Also, you can use `fo:single-page-master-reference` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_single-page-master-reference) instead of `<fo:repeatable-page-master reference maximum-repeats="1" />`. Lastly, if all else fails, you could use XSLT to generate a stylesheet module for the `fo:page-sequence-master` that has 1,000 `fo:single-page-master-reference` in it then never have to look at the module again once it's shown to work.

Answer (score 1):

For Apache-FOP I don't see any alternative as to generate/create those `fo:repeatable-page-master-reference`.

Maybe you are able to somehow estimate how many pages the pdf will become and then use xsl to generate this set of fo:repeatable-page-master-reference's.

An alternative could be using XEP and use the intermediate xep-file to adjust color per page.

Comment: Creating an intermediate file and modifying it to set the proper color seems a very good idea. Note that FOP has an [intermediate format](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.6/intermediate.html) too.